# routing issue passing id rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, routes

Firstly apologies as just when i think i have a grip on routing i find that i don't!!

When a registered user logs in to my app they are taken to the admin index view and all i am trying to do is display their user name within that view.

This is my routes config: -

```
Easygifts::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'admin' => 'admin#index' 
    controller :sessions do
        get 'login' => :new
        post 'login' => :create
        delete 'logout' => :destroy
    end
  get "sessions/create"
  get "sessions/destroy"
  resources :users 
  resources :admin 

    resources :stores do
        collection do
          get "writing"
          get "office"
          get "time"
          get "home"
          get "wellness"
          get "travel"
          get "bags"
          get "leisure"
          get "contact"
          get "terms"
         end
          member do
          get 'quote'
         end
        end

    resources :products
```

Users login via the sessions controller and are passed on to the Admin controllers index view.  Where i am trying to display their name using the following: - `<th colspan="2">Welcome <%= @users.name %></th>`

The Sessions controller: -

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
    skip_before_action :authorize
  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.find_by(name: params[:name])
    if user and user.authenticate(params[:password]) 
        session[:user_id] = user.id 
        redirect_to admin_url 
    else 
        redirect_to login_url, alert: "Invalid user/password combination" 
    end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to stores_url, notice: "Logged out"
  end
end
```

The Users Controller: -

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_user, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /users
  # GET /users.json
  def index
    @users = User.order(:name)
  end

  # GET /users/1
  # GET /users/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /users/new
  def new
    @user = User.new
  end

  # GET /users/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(user_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully created." }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /users/1
  # PATCH/PUT /users/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.update(user_params)
        format.html { redirect_to users_url, notice: "User #{@user.name} was successfully updated." }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /users/1
  # DELETE /users/1.json
  def destroy
    begin 
    @user.destroy
        flash[:notice] = "User #{@user.name} deleted" 
    rescue StandardError => e 
        flash[:notice] = e.message
    end
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to users_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_user
      @user = User.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def user_params
      params.require(:user).permit(:name, :password, :password_confirmation, :add1, :add2, :add3, :add4, :post_code, :home_tel, :mobile, :ice_tel, :ni_number, :position, :image_url, :staff_num, :start_date, :birthday)
    end
end
```

And the Admin Controller: -

```
class AdminController < ApplicationController
  def index
  @users = User.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

My first point of confusion is whether i should be going through the Sessions controller or the Users controller?

If it's in the Sessions controller am i supposed to write something like `get 'admin#index' => :show`

Or if it's in Users am i to write something like `resources :users do   member do get 'admin' end end`

I think i have to define a controller with an action within my routes but i don't understand in this instance how to work out who is doing what.

Comment: I'm not fully sure I understand your question(s), but if you are trying to display something about the currently logged in user without routing them somewhere that displays their id you could do `@user = User.find(session[:user_id])`

Comment: ptd, thank you so much you have resolved my issue straight away.

Am i right in thinking that we are passing the user id within the session controller as a parameter for @user?